# Bootstrap Buttons "Loading..." When Clicked

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I cannot figure out how to get this feature on my buttons.

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html

If you click "buttons" it should take you to the clickable loading button.

```
<input class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-block" type='submit' value='Get Quotes' data-loading-text="Loading...">
```

I think my issue is that I'm not sure where to put the JS to get this working. Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate the button() component on the input, and then change it's state accordingly when the button is clicked..

```
$('#myBtn').button();

$('#myBtn').click(function(){

  $('#myBtn').button('loading');

  /* perform processing then reset button when done */
  setTimeout(function() {
       $('#myBtn').button('reset');
  }, 1000);

});
```

### [Bootply](http://bootply.com/98586)

Comment: Still wish I knew what you were talking about.

Comment: The button 'loading..' state just doesn't happen automatically. You need to use jquery (as shown) to get this to happen when the button in clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function ValidateSignUpForm() {
        //if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate('EmailBlast'))) {
        //    Page_ClientValidate();
        //}
        Page_ClientValidate('EmailBlast');
        if (Page_IsValid) {
            $('#SignUpBtn').button('loading');
            EmailSignUpCallback.PerformCallback();
            SignUpLoadingPanel.Show();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then call the function 'ValidateFormSignUp' on the CLICK of the button like so

```
<button type="submit" role="button" runat="server" id="SignUpBtn" name="SignUpBtn" onclick="ValidateSignUpForm(); return false;" class="btn btn-primary" validationgroup="EmailBlast" data-loading-text="Saving..." causesvalidation="true"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Subscribe</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- add this font awesome and jQuery CDN in the header -->

<!-- font awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

<!--  jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>


<!-- HTML Button -->
<button type="submit" id="myBtn" class="btn btn-primary mr-2" >
 enter code here<i id="loader" class=""></i>Submit
</button>


<!-- Add this Script above body tag -->
<script>

        $('#myBtn').click(function(){

        $('#loader').attr('class', 'fa fa-spinner fa-spin mr-2');

        });
</script>
```